# Display the last year in a choice type field

Tags: php, symfony, date, formatting, twig

I want to display in a year field (choice type field) just the last year (every year he will choose just the year before)

to extract the last year I am used to use :  `$year=  date("Y")-1;`

but how can I put this in the buildForm :and the  'Year' will be replaced also with the last year not displaying the word year

```
$builder->add('year', ChoiceType::class, array(
'choices'  => array(
    'Year' => '$year=  date("Y")-1)'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for this oneliner:

```
$oneYearAgo = (new \DateTime('1 year ago'))->format('Y');
```

Or same on 2 lines

```
$oneYearAgo = new \DateTime('1 year ago');
$oneYearAgo = $oneYearAgo->format('Y');
```

Or another approach

```
$dateTime = new \DateTime();
$dateTime->sub(new \DateInterval('P1Y'));
$oneYearAgo = $dateTime->format('Y');
```

As a oneliner:

```
$oneYearAgo = (new \DateTime())->sub(new \DateInterval('P1Y'))->format('Y')
```

And to answer your question:

```
$oneYearAgo = (new \DateTime('1 year ago'))->format('Y');

$builder->add('year', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices'  => [
        $oneYearAgo => $oneYearAgo,
    ],
]);
```